# Unexpected call to method or property access while drawing svg image onto canvas in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

i am trying to draw an svg image on a canvas like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width=w;
canvas.height=h;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = src;
img.onload = function(e)
{
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
}
```

it works fine on chrome, but in IE (v11 as of this writing) it gives a `Unexpected call to method or property access` error intermittently.

[image]

i have a sample jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/siddjain/sn9e615h/). note you may have to run the fiddle a couple of times, but you will run into the error eventually.

What is the problem and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had same kind of a problem. In the end, kicking drawImage out of the thread with setTimeout() helped. What the problem was, i have no answer, the most logical seems to be that sometimes img is not really ready when load event fires. Go figure.

Comment: yes that is the solution that avoided the error for me as well. its clearly a bug in IE.

Comment: yay. a bug in IE but ignored by the IE team. see https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809823/draw-svg-image-on-canvas-context .And IE11 support is discontinued, see https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/946521/unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access-while-drawing-svg-image-onto-canvas-in-ie-11

Comment: do you have code snippet of how you accomplished this?

Comment: If you could share a code snippet of how you solved this, that'd be super helpful. did you run drawImage() inside of a drawing loop? or somewhere else.